# Coveo Search REST Endpoint () 503

Tags: search, sitecore, sitecore7.2

I am facing an issue with sitecore coveo installation on my dignostic page

```
The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable. (Hide details)
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Coveo.SearchProvider.Applications.StateVerifier.<>c__DisplayClassd.<GetRestEndpointState>b__c()
   at Coveo.SearchProvider.Applications.BaseVerifier.VerifyComponent(Func`1 p_VerifyMethod, String p_ComponentName)
```

although i have found some solutions related to this on forums but not one reflect the same.
https://answers.coveo.com/questions/1974/rest-endpoint-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-503-server-unavailable
same goes for below error not reflecting or fixed by using provided solution.
https://developers.coveo.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=14058186

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Does Coveo Admin pages works for you? http://localhost:8081/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you get a "Server Unavailable" exception for the "Coveo Search REST Endpoint" component, you should ensure that:

- The "Coveo Search API" software is installed either on the Coveo Enterprise Search server or the Sitecore server depending on your infrastructure.
- The "Coveo Search API" Windows service is started on the machine it was installed on.
- The "Coveo Search API" logs doesn't contain recent errors that may prevent it to run correctly.
- The "Coveo Search API" listening port (default is 8080) is not used by any other software on the machine the "Coveo Search API" was installed on.
- The "Coveo Search API" listening port is not blocked by any firewall.
- The server on which Sitecore is installed do not block requests to the "Coveo Search API" listening port.
- You can access the "Coveo Search API" URL (default is http://ServerName:8080/rest/search) from a browser on the server on which it is installed.
- You can access the "Coveo Search API" URL from a browser on the server on which Sitecore is installed.
- You can access the "Coveo Search API" URL from a browser on another computer.
- You can access the Coveo for Sitecore REST Endpoint proxy URL (default is http://SitecoreInstanceHost/coveo/rest) from a browser on the server on which Sitecore is installed. (/coveo/rest must be in lowercase)
- You can access the Coveo for Sitecore REST Endpoint proxy URL from a browser on another computer.

Let me know if it helps.

Jeff